# How can I use macOS Monterey's new "Mic Mode" feature with Zoom?

Tags: macos, microphone, monterey, zoom.app

I want to use the new Mic Mode to block background noise, but the option is greyed out when using Zoom.

How can I use this new feature with 3rd party apps?

[image: Mic Mode is greyed out]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The third party apps will need to be reprogrammed to call the Apple code that enables this.

> In order to use Mic Modes, your app must adopt the Core Audio AUVoiceIO audio unit. This is a popular interface in video conferencing apps, since it performs echo cancellation. And Mic Mode processing is only available on 2018 and later iOS and macOS devices. With Portrait and Mic Modes, the user is always in control, but you can prompt them to turn the feature off or on by calling the new AVCaptureDevice .showSystemUserInterface method.

Apple Developer session that covers Mic Modes is available online here: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc21/10047?time=1384

You would need to [ask Zoom](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/requests/new) / relevant company what version of their apps support this and then update your app version once they program this in.

Comment: The specific quote is at https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10047/?time=1457